# Android Glide failing to load image

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to load an image into an ImageView using the Glide library. The URL that I pass into the `load()` method points to an endpoint ('/api/user/5/logo'), which then returns the image. For some reason this doesn't seem to work.

However if I pass a URL that points directly to an image ('www.example.com/logo.png'), it works perfectly.

How do I get Glide to work perfectly with the required web service?

To recap, this works:

```
Glide.with(getContext())
        .load("www.example.com/content/logo.png")
        .centerCrop()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.mark)
        .into(imageView);
```

.. and this doesn't:

```
Glide.with(getContext())
        .load("www.example.com/api/user/5/logo")
        .centerCrop()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.mark)
        .into(imageView);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Glide.with(getContext())
 .load("http://www.example.com/api/user/5/logo").centerCrop().into(imageview)
```